# 3x3 ODE system $y'=t^2A+B$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> $$y_1'=-6t^2y_2+2y_3+6t^2$$
> $$y_2'=\frac 32 t^2y_1+6t^2y_2-y_3-3t^2$$
> $$y_3'=y_1+2y_2+2t^2y_3$$
> Find the solution verifying the initial condition $y_1(0)=0, y_2(0)=1, y_3(0)=0$.

So this seems straight forward enough. We have to find the fundamental matrix of the homogenous system first. We can write the system like so:

$$y'=t^2A+B$$
Where $A= \begin{bmatrix}0&-6& 0\\3/2&6&0\\0&0&3 \end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}0&0& 2\\0&0&-1\\1&2&0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Now this is where it gets confusing (or maybe I'm ovecomplicating things). In the exercises whenever there would be two matrices like this, we could express one in terms of the other, but here I can't really see how that's possible. (B is not the inverse of A, neither is it the square, etc.) And I also noticed that $B^3=0$, so could that help us in any way?

Then I was like, okay, we have these two separate matrices, let's see what their eigenvalues are. And, if my calculations are right, $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvector $(-2, 1, 0)$.

So... how do I get to the fundamental matrix from here? We saw that in cases where $y'=Ay$ the solution is of the form $e^{\lambda t}v$. But in a case like this one, how do things work?

Comment: You could start by looking at $u=y_1+2y_2$, the system is constructed such that the resulting equation is scalar and solvable. Then $y_3$ becomes accessible, after that there are many ways to get $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: ooooo smart move! thanks!

Comment: if you could give more details i would appreciate it v much :)

Comment: In the end, this is almost the same as you are doing. Only that the useful linear combinations of the variables result from the common left eigenvectors of the matrices. (There is an error in $B_{32}$.)